# List of Lists: how to add a trailing 0 for each List except the last one?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, higher-order-functions

List of Lists: how to add a trailing 0 for each List except the last one?

I'm learning Scala. I have a List of Lists, like below:

```
List(List(1,2,3), List(15, 17, 21), List(28, 5, 7))
```

My aim is to add a trailing 0 for each List except the last one, like below:

```
List(List(1,2,3, 0), List(15, 17, 21, 0), List(28, 5, 7))
```

My solution is like below:

```
def addZero(lines: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
     def helper(nums: List[Int]): List[Int] = nums match {
       case Nil => 0 :: Nil
       case hd :: tl => hd :: helper(tl)
     }

     lines match {
       case Nil => Nil
       case hd :: Nil => hd
       case hd :: tl => helper(hd) ++ addZero(tl)
     }
}
```

But I'm not sure if there is more elegant way. I tried `flatMap` and `foldLeft` but they add 0 to every List
including the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  list.init.map { _ :+ 0 } :+ list.last
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(15, 17, 21), List(28, 5, 7)) match {
  case begin :+ last => begin.map(_ :+ 0) :+ last
}
```

In details: you first pattern match the list of lists in order to easily extract the elements of the list which are not the last one.

```
"begin" represents List(List(1, 2, 3), List(15, 17, 21))
"last" represents List(28, 5, 7)
```

You then add the 0 in last position of each list

```
_ :+ 0 // List(15, 17, 21) => List(15, 17, 21, 0)
```

And finally you add back the last element

Comment: You can use `l +: 0` to append an element instead of double reverse.